# CGContextDrawPDFPage is drawing the page on the wrong origin point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, cgcontext

**Edit:** It seems that the origin point's components are been multiplied by 2 when drawing the PDF page. Is something I'm doing causing this?

I have a UIViewController that displays a PDF page on a UIScrollView. the PDF page itself is drawn on a CATiledLayer, however, when my view controller draws the layer there is a considerable offset between the layer's bounds and the drawn PDF. As you can see in the picture, the page should have been drawn on the yellow view:

[image: The PDF is drawn with a considerable offset from it's desired origin]

Here is the relevant code that draws the page:

```
- (void)refreshPage
{

    if(contentView) {
        for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
            [v release];
        }
    }

    CGRect pageRect = CGRectIntegral(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(self._document.page, kCGPDFCropBox));

    pageRect.origin.x = ((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (pageRect.size.width / 2));

    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    tiledLayer.delegate = self;
    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0);
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 1000;
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 1000;
    tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;

    contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect];
    [contentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];

    //[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
    //[contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.contentSize = pageRect.size;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1000;
    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];   

    pagingViewController = [[PDFPagingViewController alloc] initWithDocument:self._document AndObserver:self];
    [self.view addSubview:pagingViewController.view];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return contentView;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if(self._document) {
        [layer setBackgroundColor:(CGColorRef)[UIColor redColor]];

        CGRect drawingRect = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx);

        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, drawingRect);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(self._document.page, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, self._document.page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change when you set the pageRect's origin (which I assume you do to center in the view). You are setting both the layer's frame and the contentView's frame to the offset `pageRect` when you really intend to offset only one.

```
-(void)refreshPage {
//...

CGRect pageRect = CGRectIntegral(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(self._document.page, kCGPDFCropBox));

CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
//...
tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;

// set the pageRect origin now to center the contentView, not the layer
pageRect.origin.x = ((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (pageRect.size.width / 2));

contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect];
[contentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];

//...
}
```

Comment: In addition to fixing the code as you said I also had to immediately change the pageRect's origin to { 0, 0 } as for some reason there are some PDF files that already have a predefined offset.